# Provider feature filter causes QGIS rendering to stop

Tags: qgis, filter

I'm running QGIS 2.14.0 Essen on OSX 10.11.5.

I would like to create a simple thematic map showing a subset of points over a basemap with state and county boundaries. I used an IN query in the 'Provider feature filter' for a point shapefile of towns and it appears to work. I'm not sure when it happens but either after defining symbology or turning on/off a layer, the canvas becomes unresponsive. I cannot zoom with tools or by scrolling on the mouse, I can turn layers on/off in the table of contents, but it is not reflected on the canvas and when I try to pan, it snaps back to a locked canvas.

I thought something had happened with my old map project, so I started over to find the same thing happening.

Any thoughts?